# How can I manipulate this chess notation with python?

Tags: python, data-manipulation, chess, python-chess

I'm trying to use some chess related libraries in python (e.g. chessnut and chess) and they use the following notation

> r1bqkb1r/pppp1Qpp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1K1NR b KQkq - 0 4

I've searched about it and didn't find anything. How can I manipulate this and how can I transform the standart algebraic notation (e.g. "d4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f6 dxe5 fxe5") into this new one?

Comment: That's a snapshot of the current board, not an alternative notation for moves. `python-chess` uses [algebraic notation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html?highlight=algebraic#chess.Board.push_san) for moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FEN info : [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth–Edwards_Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)

There are two ways to obtain a FEN from a san in python :
With a `.pgn` file :

```
import chess
import chess.pgn

pgn = open("your_pgn_file.pgn")
game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)
board = game.board()

for move in game.mainline_moves():
    board.push(move)
print(board.fen())
```

or from a single san mainline :

```
import chess

board = chess.Board()
san_mainline = "d4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f6 dxe5 fxe5"

for move in san_mainline.split():
    board.push_san(move)
print(board.fen())
```

Answer (score 3):

That notation is called FEN ([Forsyth–Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)), and it looks like python-chess knows about it and can parse it.

This notation is not really equivalent to a list of moves - this is for specifying a position, which might also be a starting position. There's no complete record of how the game reached that point.

Python-chess can turn any board position you've loaded into it - for example using PGN notation - into this notation though.

Comment: For the function that I'm making I need to generate the board for each move, so I think that this notation will be a lot more helpfull than the algebraic one. Tks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `python-chess` to do the job. Here is the code that takes the SAN string and makes those moves on a board:

```
import chess
san = 'd4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f6 dxe5 fxe5'
board = chess.Board()
for move_san in san.split(' '):
    board.push_san(move_san)
```

Comment: tks, this solves my problem.